# Electron does not show the images not stored when compiling the application

Tags: javascript, node.js, compilation, electron, electron-forge

I have a project where I download an FTP images, I store them and I show them

These images are loaded into the src attribute of an img tag

When I work with npm start the application works correctly.

On the other hand, when I compile (electron-forge make) I only have access to the images already existing in the compilation. The images that I download from the application are not visible

The images downloaded and those of the project have the same permissions and the application has webSecurity: false

```
<button type="button" id="family_1">
    <span>Family 1</span>
    <img src="/home/miguelcastro/xxx/xxx/xx/src/Cache/Images/Family/1.png" data-image="1.png">
</button>
```

I can see this image because I have it inside the project when I compile this

```
<button type="button" id="family_1">
    <span>Family 1</span>
    <img src="/home/miguelcastro/xxx/xxx/xx/src/Cache/Images/Family/2.png" data-image="2.png">
</button>
```

On the other hand, this one, which is identical, is not rendered, the difference is that I downloaded this image through an FTP

The image is stored correctly and is in the correct path

```
ipcRenderer.on('printImage', (event, arg) => {
    var divImage = document.getElementById(idDiv)
    if (divImage !== null && divImage !== undefined)
        divImage.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].src = arg.pathImage
})
```

Once I save the image I issue an event from the main to the renderer and I pass the path of the image, pathImage

Comment: Add some portion of your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can bypass the checker of electron forge with this portion of code

```
import { addBypassChecker } from 'electron-compile';

addBypassChecker((filePath) => { return filePath.indexOf(app.getAppPath()) === -1 && (/.jpg/.test(filePath) || /.ms/.test(filePath) || /.png/.test(filePath)); });
```